# Creating event based job/scheduler in oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle, triggers, scheduling

I have an oracle trigger which acts just after insert, update or delete on a table1 and updates the price column/value on table2 based on the dates that it gets on the table1.

Only the current price (the price on the current date) needs to be updated on the table2. For example I insert a record on table1 for a future date say between 28/01/2016 to 30/01/2016. I need the price to be updated on the table2 not until 28/01/2106. How can we get this functionality to happen automatically.

Comment: An approach can be: create a table where your trigger stores the updates to do, with the date in which every update has to happen; then create a job that runs everyday, scanning that table and executing the updates stored for the current date.

Comment: @Aleksej, thanks will try and see i can get through to it.

Answer (score 0):

Submit a DBMS JOB to run daily.. Write a procedure like an example below to scan and apply the channges to be done today . And call it through job.

```
exec dbms_job.submit(:OUTJOBNO, 'check_price_changes;', TRUNC(SYSDATE)+1, 'TRUNC(SYSDATE)+1');
-- This will run it everyday nightly.
```